# Row in Flexbox wrap, but align-content: space-between doesn't work

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some problems with the property "align-content: space-between".
With "justify-content" i add "space-between" the flex-items and now i want to add space between the different wrapped rows.

CSS

```
article > div {
    align-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#preview {
    background-color: black;
    width: 49.5%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<article>
  <div>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <div id="preview"> 

        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        <?php } ?> 

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>


     </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

</article>
```

Comment: PHP is of no use here...We need an HTML/CSS demo of the actual issue, it's hard to tell what the issue is

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of what your problem is but try this code here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/8oas8qae/) and resize the window to see if the wrap behaviour is what you expect :

```
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;  
}

.child{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: blueviolet; 
}
```